# jsonb postgres get select array row anidate child json

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Hi i have a json with this structure

[image]

```
"units":[   "weeks": [  
   {  
      "sessions":[  
         {  
            "subject":"",
            "activities":[  
               {  
                  "modality":"",
                  "description":"",
                  "type_activity":"",
                  "label_description":""
               }
            ],
            "number_session":1
         }
      ],
      "number_week":"1"
   },
   {  
      "sessions":[  
         {  
            "subject":"",
            "activities":[  
               {  
                  "modality":"",
                  "description":"",
                  "type_activity":"",
                  "label_description":""
               }
            ],
            "number_session":1
         }
      ],
      "number_week":"2"
   },
   {  
      "sessions":[  
         {  
            "subject":"",
            "activities":[  
               {  
                  "modality":"",
                  "description":"",
                  "type_activity":"",
                  "label_description":""
               }
            ],
            "number_session":1
         }
      ],
      "number_week":"3"
   },
   {  
      "sessions":[  
         {  
            "subject":"",
            "activities":[  
               {  
                  "modality":"",
                  "description":"",
                  "type_activity":"",
                  "label_description":""
               }
            ],
            "number_session":1
         }
      ],
      "number_week":"4"
   }
]]
```

So I tried to retrieve all weeks with value number_week and session in array so I have this query

```
select value->'weeks'->'number_week' as title
 from  syllabus_programs
 cross join jsonb_array_elements(program_json->'units')

 where id =12;
```

but not works.How I can retrie values correclty, i have null values but i find values in my table.

### I expected get this result

### number_week

```
1
2
3
```

If i can acces only value->'weeks' returns json with key and values but i can`t acces to this value.

Comment: "*but not works*" is not a good problem statement. Explain what is not working, are you getting an error? or wrong result? Can you post the json in simple plain-text format,also showing the expected result from the json?

Comment: Hi i add more detail

Comment: I'm afraid it is not at all clear to me what you're trying to explain. As I said, provide a simple json text in plain-text and show what's the expected output in tabular format. That is  all what I'm asking.

Comment: Hi @KaushikNayak I add muy content json and how i expected get the result